# Is there a way I dump the result into a log for caret?

Tags: r, machine-learning, caret

I am using R's package caret to train a model.

I use tune grid to train on 100 combinations of hyper parameters

It takes 1 day to train.

However, I am working with other people and sometimes I need to relieve the resource to others.

Is there a way to store/cache/dump the already finished training results? Say I already finished training of 60 combinations of parameters, so I can start from middle of the training, no need to restart overall?